# Combining data from Two Identical tables using SQL query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

We have a few different tables with identical structure.
The goal is to take data from each one of them daily into one master table.

Along the way we need to add two columns too one for serial other for keeping the track of which table this record came from (e.g. table1, table2 etc)

There is a common unique column like CustomerID to join these table.
What do you think would be the best approach.

Comment: I assume your tables are in hive? Do you you want to use the sql, r, scala or , python API? What have you tried so far? Can you load one table into the master table?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about tags you used, only some Oracle SQL.

The way you described it, it looks as if `UNION` might help.

Create a view as

```
create or replace view v_data as
  select 'tab 1' source_table, 
         id, 
         name, 
         address
    from table_1
  union
  select 'tab 2' source_table, 
         id, 
         name, 
         address
    from table_2;
```

You said that you need a "serial" number; you'd use something like a "sequence" (in Oracle, it is an object that - generally speaking - returns distinct value each time you fetch from it):

```
create sequence seq_tab;
```

Finally, to insert rows into a "master" table, you'd

```
insert into master
  (source_table,
   serial,
   id,
   name,
   address
  )
select v.source_table,
       seq_tab.nextval,
       v.id,
       v.name,
       v.address
from v_data v
where (v.source_table, v.id) not in (select a.source_table, a.id
                                     from master a
                                    )
```

`where` clause is used to skip rows which are already inserted into the `master` table.

---

Such a principle *should* work. Syntax you need might be different, as well as source for the `serial` column (I don't know whether your database supports sequences, or offers something similar).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the union option works. Issue is that we get to use only one Select query. Because this query will be executed from within another python script. Our provision to create temp tables or queries starting other than select is not there.